# Find largest of two lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, max

The following code does not seem to work. Why is this the case

```
largestList :: [a] -> [b] -> c

largestList x y = max((length x) (length y))
```

Comment: `length` returns an `Int` so your type signature should be `[a] -> [b] -> Int`

Comment: I think your function name is misleading; it doesn't yield the larger of the two given lists. It yields the *length* of the larger list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell doesn't use parentheses for apply arguments to functions, only for grouping a single argument.  How you have it now with `(length x) (length y)` is telling the compiler that you're applying the argument `(length y)` to the function `(length x)`, and `length x` isn't a function, it's an `Int`.  Drop your outermost parentheses to fix this problem:

```
largestList x y = max (length x) (length y)
```